# Weighted phase Laplacian formula

Tags: python, mathematics, numpy

We have the following equation (weighted phase Laplacian):

\$c_{i,j} = U(i,j)\Delta^{^x}_{i,j} - U(i-l, j)\Delta^{x}_{i-1,j} + V(i,j)\Delta^{y}_{i,j} - V(i,j-1)\Delta^{y}_{i,j-1}\$

Where

\$U(i,j) = min(w^2_{i+1}, w^2_{i+1})V(i,j) = min(w^2_{j+1}, w^2_{j+1})\$

with \$U, V, \Delta \$ `(N,N)` matrices

I coded the following code:

```
def compute_Weights(w):
    U = np.zeros_like(w)
    V = np.zeros_like(w)
    U = np.minimum(w[1:, :]**2, w[:-1, :]**2)
    V = np.minimum(w[:, 1:]**2, w[:, :-1]**2)

    """add the last ones rows and cols
    """
    U = np.vstack((U, U[-1]))
    V = np.vstack((V.T, V.T[-1])).transpose()

    return U, V

def Gradient(p1, p2):
    r = p1 - p2
    if r > np.pi:
        return r - 2 * np.pi
    if r < -np.pi:
        return r + 2 * np.pi
    return r
"""
    phase is not flattened
    wts are flattened
"""
def ComputePhaseLaplacian(phase, U, V):
    rows, cols = phase.shape
    phi = phase.flatten()
    rho = np.zeros_like(phi)

    for j in range(rows):
        for i in range(cols):
            k = j * rows + i
            k1 = k + 1 if i < cols - 1 else k - 1
            k2 = k - 1 if i > 0 else k + 1
            k3 = k + cols if j < rows - 1 else k - cols
            k4 = k - cols if j > 0 else k + cols


            w1 = U[k]
            w2 = U[k-1] if i > 0 else U[k]
            w3 = V[k]
            w4 = V[k-cols] if j > 0 else V[k]

            rho[k] = w1 * Gradient(phi[k], phi[k1]) \
                + w2 * Gradient(phi[k], phi[k2]) \
                + w3 * Gradient(phi[k], phi[k3]) \
                + w4 * Gradient(phi[k], phi[k4])

    return rho
```

I want to know if there is a "pythonic way" to write this. I'm a C/C++ programmer so this was my perspective. Maybe something to avoid to work with flattened arrays, and to work with 2D arrays.

I.e:

```
phase = np.load('phase.npy') #phase 512x512 float array
U,V = ComputeWeigths(W) #W 512x512 float array with values in (0,1)
uphase = ComputePhaseLaplacian(phase, U, V) #uphase 512x512 float array
```

Comment: very strange use of docstrings...  See [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for the proper usage.

Comment: Sorry, I put it just to clarify some of the code here. But thank you it is useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points.  In your code, some of these render others irrelevant, but they may be relevant in other code you write:

1. Try to follow PEP8
2. It should be possible to vectorize `ComputePhaseLaplacian`.
3. It is better to loop over rows and columns directly rather than looping over indexes.  You can use `enumerate` to keep track of the rows and columns.
4. You shouldn't flatten, you can index in two dimensions.
5. Instead of `vstack`, you should use `pad` in this case.
6. You create `U` and `V`, then immediately overwrite them.  This is redundant.
7. You should use `ravel` instead of `flatten` since it doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Have you any idea about vectorizing ComputePhaseLaplacian?

Comment: I would first generate four copies of `phi`, each one shifted by one element to handle the `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, and `k4` cases.  `w1` and `w3` are just `U` and `V`.  `w2` and `w4` are again just a shifted `U` and `V`.  `Gradient` can be converted to logic indexing on the resulting arrays.