# Vectorizing in Python

Tags: python, mathematics, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code:

```
for j in range(rows):
    for i in range(cols):
        k = j * rows + i

        k1 = k + 1 if i < cols - 1 else k - 1
        k2 = k - 1 if i > 0 else k + 1
        k3 = k + cols if j < rows - 1 else k - cols
        k4 = k - cols if j > 0 else k + cols


        w1 = U[k]
        w2 = U[k-1] if i > 0 else U[k]
        w3 = V[k]
        w4 = V[k-cols] if j > 0 else V[k]

        zarray[k] = (w1 + w2 + w3 + w4) * parray[k] - (w1 * parray[k1] + w2 * parray[k2] + w3 * parray[k3] + w4 * parray[k4])
```

I want to know if there is a way to vectorize this loops, because I think that exists a kind of "convolution" for `zarray`.

`U` and `V` are arrays representing 2D matrices with `512x512` elements, and `parray` is also a 2D representation with `512x512` elements.

In a previous [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93995/weighted-phase-laplacian-formula) vectorization was recommended, but now I can not figure out how to vectorize when I have different indices operations.

Comment: This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was the one who recommended vectorizing.  I think the first approach would be to convert your code to using 2D indexes.  I think this will make the vectorizing clearer:

```
for j in range(rows):
    for i in range(cols):
        i1 = i+1 if i<cols-1 else i-1
        i2 = i-1 if i>0 else i+1
        j1 = j+1 if j<rows-1 else j-1
        j2 = j-1 if j>0 else j+1

        w1 = U[j, i]
        w2 = U[j, i-1] if i > 0 else U[j, i]
        w3 = V[j, i]
        w4 = V[j-1, i] if j > 0 else V[j, i]

        p = parray[j, i]
        p1 = parray[j, i1]
        p2 = parray[j, i2]
        p3 = parray[j1, i]
        p4 = parray[j2, i]

        zarray[j, i] = (w1 + w2 + w3 + w4)*p - (w1*p1 + w2*p2 + w3*p3 + w4*p4)
```

So, if I am reading this code right, you are shifting some rows and columns around.  So the next step is to re-implement this by making copies of the arrays that follow the same patterns:

```
U1 = np.empty_like(U)
V1 = np.empty_like(V)
parray1 = np.empty_like(parray)
parray2 = np.empty_like(parray)
parray3 = np.empty_like(parray)
parray4 = np.empty_like(parray)

U1[:, 1:] = U[:, :-1]  # this is w2
V1[1:, :] = V[:-1, :]  # this is w4
U1[:, 0] = U[:, 0]
V1[0, :] = V[0, :]

parray1[:, :-1] = parray[:, 1:]  # this is the result of k1
parray2[:, 1:] = parray[:, :-1]  # this is the result of k2
parray3[:-1, :] = parray[1:, :]  # this is the result of k3
parray4[1:, :] = parray[:-1, :]  # this is the result of k4

parray1[:, -1] = parray[:, -2]
parray2[:, 0] = parray[:, 1]
parray3[-1, :] = parray[-2, :]
parray4[0, :] = parray[1, :]

zarray = (U+U1+V+V1)*parray - (U*parray1 + U1*parray2 + V*parray3 + V1*parray4)
```

You could also use `np.hstack` and `np.vstack` instead of slices:

```
U1 = np.hstack([U[:, :1], U[:, :-1]])
V1 = np.vstack([V[:1, :], V[:-1, :]])

parray1 = np.hstack([parray[:, 1:], parray[:, -2:-1]])
parray2 = np.hstack([parray[:, 1:2], parray[:, :-1]])
parray3 = np.vstack([parray[1:, :], parray[-2:-1, :]])
parray4 = np.vstack([parray[1:2, :], parray[:-1, :]])

zarray = (U+U1+V+V1)*parray - (U*parray1 + U1*parray2 + V*parray3 + V1*parray4)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I just solved! Thank you a lot! I thought (w1+w2+w3+w4) would be a inconvenience, but it just was the same as de previuos one.

Comment: Just an observation: which is a better way for copying? a[:] = v or a = v.copy()?

Comment: `a[:] = v` only works if `a` is already defined, so `a = v.copy()` is better for copying the whole thing.  I guess you could pre-define the arrays using `np.empty_like` rather than by making copies, then slice those.  I am not sure whether that would save much time or not.

Comment: It turns out using `np.empty_like` is orders of magnitude faster, so I updated my answer to use it instead.

Comment: I have also added an approach using `hstack` and `vstack`.  I can't tell which is faster, my benchmarks are all over the place.

Comment: There were several errors in the code which I [fixed for you](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/94485/revisions#rev07a0ce7f-91e8-416c-a6d0-13280b3ab651).